# Approach to optimize parameters to maximize throughput via Genetic Algorithm

Tags: polynomial, optimization, genetic-algorithms

I need some ideas to approach the following problem.

**Problem:**
I need to set optimum parameters to achieve maximum output dependent on the input type.

**Input:**
I have 5 different rocks (say, various composition of different minerals) which results to different hardness.

**Parameters:**
I have 10 different machines which are lined up in a fixed sequence which does different things. Each machine (say A to J) can have different parameters (with min and max threshold). The parameters can be speed, temperature, pressure etc. Different composition of minerals within each rock influences the parameters. each of these parameters will influence the throughput for each machine, and with it, the final throughput at the end of the line.

**Outcome:** Maximum throughput (say by weight per hour) at the end of machine J (end of the line).

**My thoughts are;** 
- Unsupervised cluster to classify groups of rocks
- Genetic Algorithm to determine the optimum parameters to achieve maximum output.

Unfortunately, I do not know how to construct the objective function (which serves as the fitness test). i.e. will it be a basic multivariate coefficient equation? Will there be interaction terms between composition of minerals or machine parameters? I highly doubt the various machine parameters are independent variables. Will need to do this in R.

Comment: So what exactly are the parameters. You say you have machines with a min and max treshold, but what are the parameters that the genetic algorithm should optimize?

Comment: I've included more details above. in short. The parameters can be speed, temperature, pressure etc. Different composition of minerals within each rock influences the parameters.

Comment: What do the machines do? What is the output that needs to be maximized?

Comment: Each machine has a specific function to process the rock. the parameters for each machine influences the throughput during each process. I'd like to keep the entire chain of process optimized to maximize throughput at the end of the chain (measured in say kg per hour)

Comment: Though I am not fully understood about your problem, but apprehend it as problem multistage process in which output of one machine is input of the next machine and need to maximize the throughput of output from the final machine. This is purely an optimization problem. So do not understand where the question of clustering coming here from. A  question I am having is, are different types of rocks being used as inputs??? Are these different types of rocks are being mixed to get the final product??? If I am understanding it properly then I think I have a solution to this...

Comment: There are different rock types at the moment, and different rocks will influence the parameters. My thoughts are, if i apply unsupervised cluster, i'd find the most common groups of rock. Analyzing the composition of each group can help determine how i should set the parameters next. question is, how do i set the objective function to run the Genetic Algo (GA)